# Convert 24hour time formatted as string to 12hour time in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a column in my table that is supposed to be in 24hour format but it's a string. A screenshot is shown below.
Please how do I convert it to 12hour format in SQL.

Note; The 24hour format appears like integer

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Crime_Data;
CREATE TABLE #Crime_Data
(
    Time_Occ VARCHAR(4)
);

INSERT INTO #Crime_Data VALUES
(''),('8'),('18'),(NULL),('2130'),('345'),('1300'),('1115'),('1205'),
('1544'),('1700'),('450'),('2315'),('2030'),('2200')

SELECT  Time_Occ,
        CASE WHEN LEN(Time_Occ) <= 2
                THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), 12)
            WHEN SUBSTRING(Time_Occ, 1, LEN(Time_Occ)-2) > 12
                THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), SUBSTRING(Time_Occ, 1, LEN(Time_Occ)-2) - 12)
            ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), SUBSTRING(Time_Occ, 1, LEN(Time_Occ)-2))
        END +
        ':' +
        RIGHT('00' + Time_Occ, 2) +
        CASE WHEN LEN(Time_Occ) <= 2 OR SUBSTRING(Time_Occ, 1, LEN(Time_Occ)-2) < 12
                THEN ' AM'
            ELSE ' PM'
        END AS '12hour Format'
FROM #Crime_Data
```

Comment: I have about 680k values in crime_data. I only want to convert the TIME OCC to 12 hour format from the 24hour string it's in

Comment: @Donatus not really understand what do you means. Perhaps you can elaborate more by editing your question above, by giving some expected result maybe.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code work well for me but i ran into error      **"Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 40
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."**

Comment: @Donatus there is invalid time length in your data set. `SELECT * FROM [Your_Table] WHERE LEN(Time_Occ) < 2` query this and see what are them. You exclude this set of data and my query above should be working fine.

Comment: @Donatus from your comment error message, i can assume there is empty Time_Occ data or LEN < 2, my query updated, you may try first.

Comment: Thank you. You are a life safer. It worked. I will take time to study your code to understand the concept. Thank you once again